What's the minimum size when a simple blazor wasm project AOT compiled and trimmed?
I would like to test the binary (.wasm) file size of a Blazor Web Assembly project, I did this:
dotnet new blazorwasm -o BlazorWasm

Then I use this configurations:
    <RunAOTCompilation>true</RunAOTCompilation>
    <WasmStripILAfterAOT>true</WasmStripILAfterAOT>
    <WasmEnableExceptionHandling>false</WasmEnableExceptionHandling>
    <InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>
    <InvariantTimezone>true</InvariantTimezone>

They are from this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-build-tools-and-aot?view=aspnetcore-9.0
then I call
dotnet publish

and then I check the folder of bin/Release/net9.0/publish/wwwroot/_framework:
9.4M Nov 13 14:18 dotnet.native.gsspae0k3f.wasm*
3.3M Nov 13 14:18 dotnet.native.gsspae0k3f.wasm.gz
2.2M Nov 13 14:18 dotnet.native.gsspae0k3f.wasm.br

Here is my understanding: dotnet.native.wasm is at 9.4M before compression, and it can be compressed to 2.2M.
My question is: is it normal? Any other publish options that I missed?

Have you tried loading this in a browser and inspecting the actual downloaded size?

This is tagged with native-aot but Blazor does not use NativeAOT, rather it uses mono AOT which is different.
